# CXF STSClient asks for user+password even though there is a SAML token in onBehalfOf

Tags: jwt, cxf, saml-2.0

I'm using CXF's `STSClient` to request a JWT token on behalf of a user so I can call a REST service.

I have a valid SAML token and tried to configure the `STSClient` like so:

```
stsClient.setTokenType("urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt");
stsClient.setKeyType("http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer");
stsClient.setOnBehalfOf(samlToken.getToken());
stsClient.setEnableAppliesTo(true);

// Not sure about these.
stsClient.setSendRenewing(false);
stsClient.setKeySize(0);
stsClient.setRequiresEntropy(false);

final Map<String, Object> requestContext = Preconditions.checkNotNull(stsClient.getRequestContext());
requestContext.put(SecurityConstants.USERNAME, name); // Without this, I get "No username available"

SecurityToken result = stsClient.requestSecurityToken(appliesTo);
```

but when the method fails with:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No callback handler and no password available
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.TransportBindingHandler.handleBinding(TransportBindingHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.issue(AbstractSTSClient.java:874)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:65)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: No callback handler and no password available
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractCommonBindingHandler.unassertPolicy(AbstractCommonBindingHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.getPassword(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:1042)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.addUsernameToken(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:839)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.TransportBindingHandler.addSignedSupportingTokens(TransportBindingHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.TransportBindingHandler.handleNonEndorsingSupportingTokens(TransportBindingHandler.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.TransportBindingHandler.handleBinding(TransportBindingHandler.java:167)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Since I have a SAML token, I was expecting that the STSClient doesn't need the user name or password anymore.

How can I tell CXF / `STSClient` to skip the `addUsernameToken()` method call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the WSDL definition of the service.

Each port in the WSDL is attached to a URL and a binding. The binding has a policy. The policy in this case requests a user name with password. Look for `UsernameToken` in the WSDL.

What you need is a port that doesn't require this. I'm no expert in this matter but from the examples I've seen, the policy must not have a `SignedSupportingTokens` element in them, only `Wss11` and `Trust13` elements.

Without this element, CXF will take a different path in the code and the error will go away.